# Finding all cells within the table instead of cells within current row in foreach loop in Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

My code is like below.

```
    private List<WebElement> reports;
    public List<WebElement> getReports(){
        return Common.returnElementList(DriverFactory.getDriver(), reportsMenu, reports);
    }
    public Map<String, String> getReportDesc() {
        Map<String, String> temp = new HashMap<>();
        for(WebElement item: getReports()){
            List<WebElement> cols = item.findElements(By.xpath("/child::td[@role='gridcell']"));
            String key = Common.getElementText(DriverFactory.getDriver(), cols.get(0));
            String desc = Common.getElementText(DriverFactory.getDriver(), cols.get(1));
            temp.put(key, desc);
        }
        return temp;
    }
```

With `item.findElements(By.xpath("/child::td[@role='gridcell']"));` I am trying to get the cells of that specific row, instead I am getting all the cells in that table.

How Can I get the specific row columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use relative XPath locator.
Since you didn't share a link to the page containing that table we can only guess. So, I guess:
Instead of

```java
item.findElements(By.xpath("/child::td[@role='gridcell']"));
```

try this:

```java
item.findElements(By.xpath(".//td[@role='gridcell']"));
```

The dot `.` infront of the XPath means this is relative XPath, we want to locate element matching `//td[@role='gridcell']` **inside** current node `item`.
Otherwise `driver` will search for **all** elements matching `/child::td[@role='gridcell']` expression form the first, top element on the page.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me, I was updating some one else's code, he had a dot(.) but some of the table rows did not have the columns with role = gridcell, that's why the code was failing, had to add a null check, but your answer helped me understand the issue.

Comment: Great to know I helped you to understand / clarify something new!